# Объединение двух массивов в один двумерный

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как два  массива

```
$x = (12, 343, 343);
$y = (22, 66, 78);
```

в один

```
$z = ((12, 22), (343, 66), (343, 78));
```

Просто что-то недопонимаю, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используя стандартную функцию [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php):

```
$result = array_map(null, $x, $y);
```

где `$x` и `$y` - ваши массивы, а `$result` - объединение.

Недостающие элементы будут заменены на `null`. Можно использовать и для большего числа массивов.

Comment: Тут вроде тоже легко. Я сам сначала написал с ``callback``'ом, а потом, увидел пример с ``null`` в документации.. магия :)

Comment: да я  весь день просидел, программировал, поэтому сейчас уже туплю, да и с php не сильно знаком.